# How to recover system path variable on windows 8 (64 bit)?

Tags: windows-8, java, path

I just deleted my system path variable while setting up java jdk. How to recover default setting?

Answer (score 0):

Use a restore point. Unless you've disabled them, restore points are automatically saved every week, and also just before most software installations. A restore point will normally not affect your own files.

You can use this even if you just can't tolerate the "backstep": Restore to the most recent restore point. Save the system path variable in a text file in your own documents directory, or desktop, or... someplace that restore points don't affect. Now restore forward again (that is, unapply the restore point). Bring up the file where you saved the path value and use the usual dialog to fix the environment variable.

As a quick fix, here is sort of a basic one with no third-party stuff added.

%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;